# For-loop in draw() Processing

Tags: for-loop, processing, draw, multidimensional-array

I put this code in the draw() function in Processing, and it doesn't work. Can someone explain why, and help me fix this? What I want it to do is to cycle through each element of the 2d boolean array and check if it is true or false.

```
for(int i = 0; i < elemts.length; i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; j < elemts[0].length; j++)
  {
    if(elemts[i][j] == true)
    {
      rect(i*5,j*5,5,5);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where's your `i++` and `j++`?

Comment: OK. Fixed it in the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you didn't add i++ or j++, so the for-loop doesn't run. Next, the draw function runs itself 60 times per second, so putting a for-loop with a certain number of elements doesn't allow the draw() to work. Use the below code instead.

```
if(elemts[x][y] == true)
{
  rect(x*5,y*5,5,5);
  fill(0,0,0);
}
if(x < elemts.length)
{
  x += 1;
}
if(x == elemts.length)
{
  x = 0;
  y += 1;
}
```

Comment: This makes a black box move across the screen and reappear on the next row.

Answer (score 2):

The for loop should be like this

```
for(start; condition; code to excute every turn)
```

When you want to skip it you should add a semicolon.